# Height of a DIV-container

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with DIV-containers.

```css
.inner-teaser {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
.bg-blue {
    background: blue;
}
.teaser-image {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
.image-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-teaser bg-blue">
    <div class="inner-teaser">
        <div class="teaser-image image-left" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg);">Image</div>
        <div class="teaser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `inner-teaser` should have the height from the `teaser-image` (250px) + 20px padding. But `inner-teaser` has only a height of 40px (2 * 20px padding).

Comment: It is just overflow issue. Fiddle updated http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhcfbut2/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.inner-teaser` to force it to take its floating-children height:

```css
.inner-teaser {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bg-blue {
    background: blue;
}
.teaser-image {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
.image-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-teaser bg-blue">
    <div class="inner-teaser">
        <div class="teaser-image image-left" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg);">Image</div>
        <div class="teaser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It can be so easy. Thx a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use { display: inline-block } for .inner-teaser div.

```css
.inner-teaser {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bg-blue {
    background: blue;
}
.teaser-image {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
.image-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-teaser bg-blue">
    <div class="inner-teaser">
        <div class="teaser-image image-left" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg);">Image</div>
        <div class="teaser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add  after class class="teaser-text" see demo :[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/318fvz5b/)

```css
.inner-teaser {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
.bg-blue {
    background: blue;
}
.teaser-image {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
.image-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-teaser bg-blue">
    <div class="inner-teaser">
        <div class="teaser-image image-left" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg);">Image</div>
        <div class="teaser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor...</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

v style="clear:both">